# How to link list in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vue-component, vue-router

```
<template>
    <div class="lists">
        <div v-for="(list, key, i) in getAllBreeds" :key="i">
            <div v-if="list.length">
                <div v-for="(ele,i) in list" :key="i" class="listOption">
                    <router-link :to="/breed/:key/:ele">
                        {{ele}} {{key}}
                    </router-link>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div v-else class="listOption">
                <router-link :to="/breed/:key/images">
                    {{key}}
                </router-link>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div
</template>
```

I am using Vue Router. I read a lot of articles and all but still I coudn't understand anything from them.

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts When i click on list it go to route "http://localhost:8080/breed/:key/:ele" .
But I want if key = 'anything' and ele = 'something' then the link must be 
"http://localhost:8080/breed/anything/something" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the links are going to `localhost:8080/breed/:key/:ele` is because you are not interpolating the values. That shorthand is only for setting attributes on elements. You'd want to change your `router-link` to look something like this:

```
<router-link :to="`/breed/${key}/${ele}`">
  {{ele}} {{key}}
</router-link>
```

Comment: Shit! how I missed this. 
Thank you So much for your quick replies and help!